# Importing a Log4j source in eclipse

Tags: java, ubuntu, log4j, log4j2, log4net-configuration

I am trying to import the latest Log4j2 source in my eclipse and Eclipse is not detecting it as a project. it says 'No projects are found to import'. Is there a solution for this?
My goal is to make a jar out of this source. Can i do that without the need to importing it on my eclipse(maybe like a command line solution that can make a build for me)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Eclipse is not detecting it as a project. it says 'No projects are found to import'. Is there a solution for this?

It's a maven project, so you should import Existing Maven Project

> Can i do that without the need to importing it on my eclipse(maybe like a command line solution that can make a build for me)?

A simple jar command. You can see more at [Using JAR Files: The Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html). A basic command example

> `> jar cf log4j-sources.jar *`  <sub>// the * is for all files in the current directory</sub>

<sub>**Note:** this will not build anything. Just put everything into a jar.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you have maven you can ask maven to generate the Eclipse .project and .classpath files.
From the log4j2 top-level folder, run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

Eclipse will now be able to recognize each module as a project.

After this, to import modules in Eclipse, take the following steps for each module:
File > New > Java Project - enter module name (e.g. log4j-api) for Project name, uncheck "Use default location" and click Browse... to navigate to the location of the log4j-api module. Then click Finish on the wizard.